# `tail` and append in oneliner

Tags: command-line, bash, tail

How could I `tail` and append a text in a file, in one line, in Bash?

My failed attempt would be

```bsh
tail file.txt > file.txt && date >> file.txt
```

Comment: what is the purpose of the `tail`? Do you want to discard the earlier lines?

Comment: i want to keep a 10 line log

Answer (score 3):

This produces unexpected results:

```
tail file.txt > file.txt && echo $(date) >> file.txt
```

The first redirection truncates the file **before** the tail process starts, so tail  is now operating on an empty file. ([ref](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Redirections))

2 suggestions:

1. a temp file:

   ```
   f=file.txt
   tmp=$(mktemp)
   { tail "$f"; date; } > "$tmp" && mv "$tmp" "$f"
   ```
2. [`sponge`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/sponge.1.html) from the [moreutils](http://packages.ubuntu.com/wily/i386/moreutils/filelist) package

   ```
   f=file.txt
   { tail "$f"; date; } | sponge "$f"
   ```

Note that `echo $(date)` is redundant: you don't need `echo` to send the output of `date` to stdout -- `date` does this by default.

Answer (score 1):

Another way without using temporary files or installing additional tools (but not efficient for large files):

```bsh
<<<"$(<file)" tail >file && date >>file
```

This reads `file` in a command substitution, guaranteeing that the reading of `file` will take place before the other redirections are resolved.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Vim in Ex mode:

```sh
ex -sc '1,-10d|x' file.txt
```

1. `1,-10` select all but last 10 lines
2. `d` delete
3. `x` save and close